# Can one Video Mixing Renderer 9 (VMR9) render more video streams?

Tags: c#, directshow.net

I am rendering a number of video streams in a Windows form, using the same number of VMR9 instances. I am doing this in C# using DirectShowLib-2005.

If there is a need to display 100 videos, I will create 100 FilterGraphs (IFilterGraph2) that will hold one VMR9 instance (VideoMixingRenderer9) each, that will each render 1 video stream.

This uses up the RAM quickly...

Can I make one VMR9 filter render more than one video stream, so I have less VMR9 instances, and more number of video streams rendered?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Well... I figured it out... if someone has a better example, please post it here, I will mark it as an accepted answer.***

The graph: 
[image: The graph I want to render with one VMR9 renderer]

If you render this in GrapgEdit (or something else) it displays the first (Input0) stream and the second one (Input1) underneath it, but I want them to be visible at the same time!

To do this, VMR9 must be configured as such *(error handling and some VMR9 configuration omitted)*:

```
//Setting VMR9 to run in WINDOWLESS MODE
filterConfig = (IVMRFilterConfig9)vmr;
filterConfig.SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode.Windowless);

//Number of streams that I want to render together (mix)
filterConfig.SetNumberOfStreams(2);

//Get the MIXER CONTROL that will be used to configure video rendering surfaces
mixerCtrl = (IVMRMixerControl9)vmr;

//*** RENDER THE PINS SO THE GRAPH CONNECTS CORRECTLY (omitted) ***

//Define areas of the clipping window that will be covered by each video stream
NormalizedRect r1 = new NormalizedRect(0,0,0.5f, 0.5f);
NormalizedRect r2 = new NormalizedRect(0.5f, 0.5f, 1f, 1f);

//For each stream (0 and 1) set the output rect
mixerCtrl.SetOutputRect(0, ref r1);
mixerCtrl.SetOutputRect(1, ref r2);
```

After this, the streams are rendered in top left and bottom right portion of the clipping window, and they are both shown and rendered correctly!!! 
[image: Shows the resulting clipping window containing 2 video streams rendered with one VMR9]

If you want to display more video streams, just `SetNumberOfStreams` accordingly, and configure `NormalizedRect` for each one. This way I can render more streams with one VMR9 instance, and I don't need to worry about RAM running out.

Now the true coolness of VMR9 shows up... :D xD

**PS**
It looks like 16 streams is the limit...